# How to find your vocal range using the guitar?

Tags: voice, vocal-range

There are other questions on this topic, but they're very unclear on which tone is which in singing vs guitar.

So if my lowest singing note is G (3rd fret e bass string) and the highest is G3 (15th fret high e string) does this mean my range is G - G3?

This is a bit confusing to me because I've read people on forums writing their range was like c2-a4 (males) and it sounds a bit too high and no bass to be true.

So - is A4 in singing the same tone as A4 is in guitar?

Comment: Bottom E on a guitar is E2. So your range is G2 to G5.

Comment: Aha I think the problem was that in ny country we're still taught that B is H and Bb is B, maybe it's the same with octaves. Teachers teach that bottom E is E bass or "small e", and e top is e2. Hence the confusion

Comment: There may be confusion as the guitar plays notes that are one octave lower than the ones that appear on the dots.

Answer (score 4):

The open guitar strings in standard tuning are `E2 A2 D3 G3 B3 E4` in [scientific pitch notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_pitch_notation), or `E2 A2 D3 G3 H3 E4` if you use H.

In [Helmholtz pitch notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_pitch_notation), they are `E A d g b e′` or `E A d g h e′`. Here small e would be E3.

A4 is A4, no matter what instrument or voice, and A4 is generally standardized to 440 Hz. (These notations remove all ambiguity and confusion; that is at least their intent.)

Confusion enters in because guitar is normally written in treble clef, one octave above where it actually sounds.

The G at the 15th fret on the high E string of a guitar is G5.